# Adding items to a combobox in DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I've a DataGridView in a winforms app.
Apart from the 4 columns coming from the db table,I need to show an additional column having a combobox in the datagridview[may be using  DataGridViewComboColumn?].
2.And then I want to  add different set of items to each combobox for every row.

How do I go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to add them via **DataBindingComplete** of the grid

Something on these lines

```
void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
       if (row.Cells[0] is DataGridViewComboBoxCell && row.Index == 1)
          (row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items.Add("A");
       else
          (row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items.Add("B");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps
**EDIT**

```
(row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = (row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[0];
```

When that cell is selected then the first value would be shown selected

Comment: Thanks a lot.This works.Could you please tell me how do I show the first item as selected in the dropdownlist in each cell?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this in VB.NET, but found the C# answer here.

In VB you can do:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataBindingComplete

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow in DataGridView1.Rows
        If TypeOf row.Cells(0) Is DataGridViewComboBoxCell AndAlso row.Index = 1 Then
            TryCast(row.Cells(0), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items.Add("A")
        Else
            TryCast(row.Cells(0), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items.Add("B")
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

To Edit:

```
TryCast(row.Cells(0), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = TryCast(row.Cells(0), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items(0)
```